# What are CSS variations?

Tags: css, variables

Im working on a website and my boss wants me to use CSS variations and I dont know what he is talking about.

Let's say I have 20 different elements using `#7d2d39`, rather than having:

```
background-color:#7d2d39
color="#7d2d39"
```

All over the style sheets he wants me to call it using:

```
background-color:red1"
color="red1"
```

and somewhere define what "red1" is that way we can globally change one hex color vs. changing it 20 times? It makes sense as I type it, but I dont think this exists.

Comment: I know this is very radical and maybe totally crazy... How about asking your boss to explain what he means? :)

Answer (score 3):

You'd need to use something like [LESS](http://lesscss.org/) which supports dynamic stylesheets and variables.

Comment: You forgot to mention the other popular CSS preprocessors:  Sass and Stylus.

Answer (score 2):

I think he is talking about [css variables](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-variables/) but this is just a draft. [LESS](http://www.lesscss.de) and [SASS](http://sass-lang.com) are options, too.

Answer (score 2):

CSS preprocessors are a way of making CSS more "programmatic" by using things like functions and variables. The two most popular are:

- [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/)
- [LESS](http://lesscss.org/)

And then there's others:

- [Google Closure Stylesheets](http://code.google.com/p/closure-stylesheets/)
- [Stylus](http://learnboost.github.com/stylus/)

And there's projects like [Twitter Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/index.html) which uses LESS.  There's nothing directly usable in CSS at this moment.  It all requires either a JavaScript or a backend processing to convert the LESS/SASS file into CSS.

But it can help developer keep code organized and cleaned and make managing updates faster.

I've never heard of the term "*CSS Variants*" before but I would suspect your boss might have meant "CSS Variables", which is more what you're describing.  But variables are only a part of the functionality preprocessors offer.

I hope that helps!